# MakeHuman Import Human Has Hole In Head Can It be Fixed

Tags: makehuman

Import figure from MakeHuman into Blender 3.6.1.
The figure imports fine except the face has a very thin mesh.
It causes problems when 3d printing small figures say 20mm tall.
It can be fixed using UVTools but it is long winded.
My question is can this be fixed easily in Blender?
The picture is Chitubox sliced image.

[image]

[image]